# C# Windows Services File Move to different directory

Tags: c#, service

Apparently changing codes blows my head.

Here's what i am facing at the moment.

I've developed a service that will extract data from an SQL which converts the data into a CSV file and then upload the file via WinSCP. Once upload finishes , the file is then moved to another directory.

However we had an upgrade and i no longer able to extract the Data from SQL as user have to manually download the file and put into my folder.

I then changed my code to remove the SQL part , and kept sequence starting from the Upload file via WinSCP.

However , now my file move no longer works with error :

> File Name couldnt be changed because : Could not find file 'Q:\FrontOffice\Nights\Qualtrics\UNPROCESSED\import-contacts.csv'.

**Is there any reason why it cannot find that file when the file and path exist?**

Note 1 : The Windows Services is installed in a Server environment. The Server has access to the network drive with admin credentials.

Note 2 : User only need to place the file into Unprocessed folder while the service will process the file and move it to Processed folder.

Here is my previous file move code :

```
string attachFileLoc = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Logs\\import-contacts-"+ DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".csv";
            var filename = Path.GetFileName(attachFileLoc);

try
            {
                System.IO.File.Move(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Automation\csvfiles\import-contacts.csv", attachFileLoc);
                WriteToFile("New File name is : " + filename);

            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                WriteToFile("File Name couldnt be changed because : " + ex.Message);
            }
```

I then modified my code to reflect to our NAS network folder.

```
string attachFileLoc = @"Q:\FrontOffice\Nights\Qualtrics\PROCESSED\import-contacts-" + DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".CSV";

try
            {
                System.IO.File.Move(@"Q:\FrontOffice\Nights\Qualtrics\UNPROCESSED\import-contacts.csv", attachFileLoc);
                WriteToFile("New File name is : " + filename);

            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                WriteToFile("File Name couldnt be changed because : " + ex.Message);
            }
```

I then tried to use other methods to obtain file location and name

```
string[] qfile = Directory.GetFiles(@"Q:\FrontOffice\Nights\Qualtrics\UNPROCESSED\", "*.CSV").FirstOrDefault();

try
            {
                System.IO.File.Move(qfile[0], attachFileLoc);
                WriteToFile("New File name is : " + filename);

            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                WriteToFile("File Name couldnt be changed because : " + ex.Message);
            }
```

but this one didnt even manage to obtain file name and location.

Edit 1 requested by mjwills :

[image]

Edit 2 requested by Caius Jard :

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199079/discussion-on-question-by-mohd-nasrul-iwan-fajaruddin-c-windows-services-file-m).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solution]

I ran debug and tried to use trycatch method to see what is going on.
Apparently I did not have enough privilege level as per conversation before with others in this thread.

I added the server into Domain as my NAS is also in a domain.
I also added the Windows Services to Log On as a Domain user.

I then proceeded to try removing the mapped drive from the Server. This does not work.

It does work when i have mapped drive or if i do mapping in my code , both while the installed services is in a Server that is in a Domain.

Conclusion :
Windows Services does use mapped drive but windows services authentication is not the same as the User Logged in or the same as the user that has the services installed with.

Solution :

Add LogOn Option to the windows services matching the network drive authentication

i.e : If Network Drive is a NAS in Domain , LogOn option should add Domain ID that has access to the required folder.

i.e2 : If Network Drive is a Shared Folder from PC21 , LogOn option should be an ID that has authentication to the required folder in PC21.

Comment: As i wrote before, you do not have a programming question.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl ya , true. Thank you Martin.  I deeply apologize on this. I ignored the rules of programming where we always need to do TryCatch method to trace the error properly.